# First part of this code is not being executed

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a flip the coin game but part of it is not being executed

```python
import time
import random

useractions = input("Enter(flip the coin): ")

possible_actions =["flip the coin", "Flip the coin"]
computeractions=random.choice(possible_actions)

if useractions == "tails":
    if computeractions == "heads":
        print("It was "+computeractions)
elif useractions == "heads":
    if computeractions == "tails":
        print(" It was "+computeractions)
elif useractions == "tails":
    if computeractions == "tails":
        print("It was "+computeractions)
elif useractions == "heads":
    if computeractions == "heads":
        print("It was "+computeractions)
```

that's the full code ^

```
 elif useractions == "tails":
        if computeractions == "tails":
            print("It was "+computeractions)
    elif useractions == "heads":
        if computeractions == "heads":
            print("It was "+computeractions)
```

That's the part that is not working ^

When I type flip the coin it either executes the first part but if it doesn't it displays nothing

Comment: it looks like `heads` or `tails` isn't an option for the computer - only `flip the coin` or `Flip the coin`

Comment: It's never going to do `elif useractions == "tails":`  because you have `if useractions == "tails":` before that. Also, all your branches end with `print("It was "+computeractions)`...why bother with all the logic if all roads lead to the same place?

Comment: Your code is logically incorrect. The condition `if useractions == "tails"` is checked only once. It is not checked again.

Comment: i added heads and tails in the possible actions but it still won't display

Comment: When you have an `if/elif/elif/elif/else` code structure, **only one** of those blocks can run. That's the *purpose* of the structure. It's not clear how you want the code to behave, or what *problem you hope to solve* by structuring it this way. It seems as if you want `print("It was "+computeractions)` to happen *no matter what*, so why is any conditional logic necessary? Just do that `print` directly.

Answer (score 1):

In your outer if/elif blocks, the first two conditions are the same as the third and fourth one, so your program always executes one of the first two branches. Looks to me like you wanted to do something like this:

```
if useractions == "tails" and computeractions == "heads":    
    print("It was "+computeractions)
elif useractions == "heads" and computeractions == "tails":
    print(" It was "+computeractions)
elif useractions == "tails" and computeractions == "tails":    
    print("It was "+computeractions)
elif useractions == "heads" and computeractions == "heads":
    print("It was "+computeractions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several issues that have already been pointed out in the comments. But to design something that is clearer and that I think achieves what you want with the advice from the comments, I think you should change the possible actions and then use a ternary operator to display the result.

This will avoid the problematic comparisons.

For instance,

```
import random

useractions = input("Heads or tails? ").lower()

possible_actions =["heads", "tails"]
computeractions=random.choice(possible_actions)

print("You got it!" if computeractions == useractions else "It was "+computeractions)
```

More on [ternary operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)

Sample output from code:
[image]